# Python Notify2 Doesn't Show Images

Tags: python, notify

I'm using notify2 module for showing desktop notifications in linux. This code gets latest earthquakes from the internet and shows desktop notifications.

The code shows notifications perfectly when I run it on spyder3 and on terminal with `python3 earthquake.py` . I've registered the code into startup applications. When I log in my computer `python3 "/home/ali/Programlarım/Python/My Projects/earthquake.py"` command works and code runs automaticly. It gets info from net and it shows notifications. But there is no icons in the notifications. How to solve this problem?

```
import requests
import time as t
import notify2 as not2
from os import getcwd
wdir=getcwd()
url="http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/scripts/lst2.asp"
ico1=wdir+"/files/earthquake.ico"
ico2=wdir+"/files/network-error.png"

def get_earthquake():        
    #get latest earthquakes from http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/scripts/lst2.asp
    url="http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/scripts/lst2.asp"
    html=["No internet connection"]
    ok=0
    
    try:
        html=requests.get(url).text
        if "Dicle University" in html:
            ok=1 
    except:
        print("Internet Connection Error")
        ok=1

    #if there is no error ok variable is equal to 0 and the program works correctly
    if ok==0: 
        #clear the text from unnecessary parts. Such as header, banner etc...
        x=(html.index("--------------"),html.index('</pre>'))
        html=html[x[0]:x[1]].splitlines()[1:500]
        
        #split the data into date, location and magnitude 
        html_=[]
        for i in html:
            html_.append(i.split(" "))
            
        html=[]
        
        for data in html_:
            scl=[] #scrape list
            for i in range(len(data)):
                if data[i]=="":
                    scl.append(i)
            scl.reverse()
            for i in scl:
                data.pop(i)
            html.append(data)
        del html_
        return html   
    else:
        print("Connect to internet") 
        return ["No internet connection"]
    
        

'''Main loop'''

while True:
    html=get_earthquake()
    if html[0]=="No internet connection":
        not2.init("Deprem")
        n=not2.Notification("Deprem","Deprem bilgilerini almak için internete bağlanın.",ico2)
        n.show()
    else:
        try:
            if not latest_earthquake==html[0]:
                not2.init("Deprem")
                output=html[0][8]+html[0][9]+" bölgesinde "+html[0][6]+" şiddetinde deprem."
                n=not2.Notification("Deprem",output,ico1)
                n.show()
                print("ok")
        except:
            not2.init("Deprem")
            output=html[0][8]+html[0][9]+" bölgesinde "+html[0][6]+" şiddetinde deprem."
            n=not2.Notification("Deprem",output,ico1)
            n.show()               
    t.sleep(60)
    latest_earthquake=html[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `ico1` really exist? This line grabs my attention: `wdir=getcwd()`

For **debugging**, try `import os;print(os.path.exists(ico1))`. This must return `True` if this is a notify2 error. Debugging is also nice with ipdb: `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()`.

If the previous output was `False`, the **solution** might be to replace `wdir=getcwd()` with `os.path.basename(__file__)`.

### Better practises:

Use `os.path.join` instead of `'/'`. E.g. instead of `ico1=wdir+"/files/earthquake.ico"`: `ico1 = os.path.join(wdir,'files','earthquake.ico')`.

Use `%s` instead of `+`. `output=html[0][8]+html[0][9]+" bölgesinde "` -> `output="%s %s bölgesinde "%(html[0][8],html[0][9])"`

You maybe want to shorten the `ok` variable:

```
#ok=0
try:
    html=requests.get(url).text
    if "Dicle University" in html:
      #ok=1
      raise
except:
    #ok=1
    print("Internet Connection Error")
    return ["No internet connection"]

#if there is no error ok variable is equal to 0 and the program works correctly
#if ok==0:
#clear the text from unnecessary parts. Such as header, banner etc...
x=(html.index("--------------"),html.index('</pre>'))
html=html[x[0]:x[1]].splitlines()[1:500]
```

For parsing HTML, you can use a framework like BeautifulSoup.